# Why string::str_split does not update the data frame upon dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have the following data frame:

```r
df <- structure(list(gene_id = c("RNA18S5", "RNA18S5", "RNA18S5", "RNA18S5", 
"RNA18S5"), samplename = c("XX_135_S14.Adipose", "XX_133_S12.Adipose", 
"XX_128_S7.Umbilical", "XX_117_S11.Liver", "XX_124_S3.Pulmonary"
), gene_expr = c(6533029L, 5494889L, 5491158L, 5232914L, 5151004L
)), .Names = c("gene_id", "samplename", "gene_expr"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df
#>   gene_id          samplename gene_expr
#> 1 RNA18S5  XX_135_S14.Adipose   6533029
#> 2 RNA18S5  XX_133_S12.Adipose   5494889
#> 3 RNA18S5 XX_128_S7.Umbilical   5491158
#> 4 RNA18S5    XX_117_S11.Liver   5232914
#> 5 RNA18S5 XX_124_S3.Pulmonary   5151004
```

What I want to do is to split the `samplename` and create new column.

I tried this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% 
   mutate(subtype=stringr::str_split(samplename,"\\.")[[1]][2])

df
```

Which gives this:

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  gene_id          samplename gene_expr subtype
    <chr>               <chr>     <int>   <chr>
1 RNA18S5  XX_135_S14.Adipose   6533029 Adipose
2 RNA18S5  XX_133_S12.Adipose   5494889 Adipose
3 RNA18S5 XX_128_S7.Umbilical   5491158 Adipose
4 RNA18S5    XX_117_S11.Liver   5232914 Adipose
5 RNA18S5 XX_124_S3.Pulmonary   5151004 Adipose
```

Note that the subtype column is incorrect. I expect the output to be:

```r
  gene_id          samplename gene_expr subtype
1 RNA18S5  XX_135_S14.Adipose   6533029 Adipose
2 RNA18S5  XX_133_S12.Adipose   5494889 Adipose
3 RNA18S5 XX_128_S7.Umbilical   5491158 Umbilical
4 RNA18S5    XX_117_S11.Liver   5232914 Liver
5 RNA18S5 XX_124_S3.Pulmonary   5151004 Pulmonary
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: You don't really need to split. `df %>% mutate(subtype = sub('.*\\.', '', samplename))` should suffice

Comment: But if you do want to split, you are better off with `str_split_fixed`... `stringr::str_split_fixed(df$samplename, "\\.", 2)[,2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `extract`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  extract(samplename, into = 'subtype', '.*\\.([^.]+)', remove = FALSE)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#  gene_id          samplename   subtype gene_expr
#*   <chr>               <chr>     <chr>     <int>
#1 RNA18S5  XX_135_S14.Adipose   Adipose   6533029
#2 RNA18S5  XX_133_S12.Adipose   Adipose   5494889
#3 RNA18S5 XX_128_S7.Umbilical Umbilical   5491158
#4 RNA18S5    XX_117_S11.Liver     Liver   5232914
#5 RNA18S5 XX_124_S3.Pulmonary Pulmonary   5151004
```